# Force on dielectric

Tags: forces, electrostatics, capacitance, dielectric

I have been taught that the magnitude of the force on a dielectric is $$F=\frac{bε_0V^{2}}{2d}\left(K-1\right)$$ **where:**

b is the width of the plate.

$V$ is the EMF of the cell to which the capacitor is connected

$d$ is the distance between the plates

and $K$ is the dielectric constant of the dielectric medium.

My doubt is that this formula is independent of $x$ or the length of the dielectric which has been inserted at the instant, or in other words, the force is independent of the location of the dielectric inside the capacitor. But, we also know that when the dielectric is in exactly the middle of the capacitor, it experiences no net force. How does this formula account for that fact? Am I missing out on something?
Does that mean the force suddenly drops to zero when placed exactly in middle?

Comment: In high school classes it is taught to approximate the field lines inside capacitors as straight, perpendicular to the plates and only present inside the capacitor. If you assume that then you might even find one more question that -" What exerts force on the dielectric ?" The answer to that question is- in reality weak field lines due to plates also exist outside the capacitor which causes force on dielectric. Hence when the dielectric is in center there is no net force on it. At rest of the position the force is nearly equal to that given by formula(actually it decreases moving centerwards).

Comment: So basically I should just go with this approximation?

Comment: yes, this expression is an approximation, it is calculated by calculating work done by the force, but in the calculation of the work done there is an approximation, they neglect energy due to field lines which are not perpendicular to the plates and exist out of the capacitor.